# Xcode can't find headers in given framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Messing round a little in Xcode, and I was trying to get my app to look at the users music library with the use of MPMediaPickerController.

Following Apples documentation, I added the MediaPlayer.framework to the project, and in my header I've imported , giving me something like this:

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface HelloMusic :  UIViewController
{

}
```

So far so simple. Now, as far as I'm aware I should be able to do

```
MPMediaPickerController *mp = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] init];
```

in my main file and set about launching my picker. Unfortunately XCode stubbronly refuses to admit that there is such a thing as an MPMediaPickerController - if I type MP and hit escape to get code complations I am without any of the MPMedia family. Annoyingly Xcode *does* recognise any MPMovie... class (from the same framework!). If I try and run the app it compiles fine so it must at least recognise the header from the framework, then chunters along until I get to the assignment of MPMediaPickerController, at which point I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, with a console output of

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
pthread_mutexattr_destroy$UNIX2003 called from function _ZN4llvm3sys5MutexC2Eb in image
libLLVMContainer.dylib.
```

I'm... certain I'm doing something beyond stupid, but I'm stuck nevertheless.

Comment: Mac OS X or iOS ? Which SDK do you have set as your base SDK ?

Comment: Sorry, it's iOS and it's 4.1 that I'm having the problem with. Oddly enough it works if I set the SDK to 3.2, but thats not really a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) states, it's declared in MPMediaPickerController.h. As such, simply adding...

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMediaPickerController.h>
```

...should solve your problems. :-)

Comment: Ahh, yeah that did it. Cheers :) Totally didn't realise I could import specific headers like that.

Comment: @MoominTroll - No probs. On the upside, you won't be bitten by this again. (The class reference documentation is your master.) :-)